# How to remove array element by different condition within one query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

Having a collection called 'posts' like this,

```
{
 _id: 1,
 user: "63109",
 comments: [
              { _id: 1, text: "john", user: "63110" },
              { _id: 2, text: "jess", user: "63109" },
              { _id: 3, text: "jeff", user: "63100" }
           ]
}
{
 _id: 2,
 user: "63110",
 comments: [
              { _id: 4, text: "ajax", user: "63100" },
              { _id: 5, text: "achilles", user: "63109" },
           ]
}
{
 _id: 3,
 user: "63109",
 comments: [
              { _id: 6, text: "ajax", user: "63110" },
              { _id: 7, text: "achilles", user: "63111" },
           ]
}
{
 _id: 4,
 user: "63111",
 comments: [
              { _id: 8, text: "barney", user: "63111" },
              { _id: 9, text: "ruth", user: "63110" },
           ]
}
```

How to implement following logic within one query user:-

Can we delete any comment if user has equal requested user id(user == 'posts.user') if not then delete only his own comment likewise user == 'posts.comments.user' .

I had tried with below query but failed.

```
var postid = 1;
var userid = 63111;
var commentid = 7;
db.collection('posts').findOneAndUpdate({_id: postid}, {$pull: {comments: {_id: commentid}}}, {
    projection: {
        $or: [
            {user: {$eq: userid}},
            {comments:{$elemMatch: {user: userid}}}]
    }
)
```

Please give me advice!

Comment: No. Those are two totally different updates. Do a different update for each case.

Comment: yes, i use two updates at the moment, but i'm thinking of a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the correct answer by myself, no need projection, just use $or condition and $elemMatch in query, pull the comment by 'commentid' in any matched document. See below:

```
var postid = 1;
var userid = 63111;
var commentid = 7;
db.collection('posts').findOneAndUpdate({$or:[
    {_id:postid, user:userid}, 
    {_id:postid, comments:{$elemMatch:{user:userid, _id:commentid}}}
]}, 
{$pull: {comments: {_id: commentid}}})
```